# Odd Lookup Issue in Saleforce Classic

Tags: lightning-experience, lookup, search, salesforce-classic

I have an odd issue where a user cannot add a campaign to an opportunity in Salesforce classic. The related lookup search returns no results, though the org wide search returns records, and the user can see all campaigns.

I've tested in lightning, and it works fine, no issue, so it looks to be isolated to classic.

I know it's not a permission issue, as the user can see the record within the campaign tab, and also search for it in the org wide search.

The sharing setting for the Campaign object is set to: "Public Full Access", which according to Salesforce documentation should mean:

> All users can view, edit, transfer, delete, and report on all records.
>   Only available for campaigns.

Has anyone come across this before?

Edit: I adjusted user permissions to have 'View All' permissions on the Campaign object, and this appeared to fix the issue, though long term I don't want to use the View All permission and would want to use the "Public Full Access" sharing rule.